# what exactly is arc length element $ds$ or area element $dA$

Tags: calculus, geometry

I am reading a book on complex analysis and it has something like:

**The spherical arc length element on the Riemann sphere ($S^2$) works out to be
$ds=\frac{|dz|}{1+|z|^2},$
and the spherical area element $dA$ is given by
$dA=\frac{dxdy}{(1+|z|^2)^2}$ for $z=x+iy$.**

Naturally, I believe that given a curve $\gamma$ and a region $\Omega$ on $S^2$, the length of $\gamma$ and the area of $\Omega$ is given by

$L(\gamma)=\int_\gamma\frac{|dz|}{1+|z|^2}, $ and

$A(\Omega)=\int_\Omega\frac{dxdy}{(1+|z|^2)^2}$, respectively.

Is my understanding correct? And if so, how to derive these formulas for $ds$ and $dA$?